# (Argument Error) thrown when trying to instantiate a custom object in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop

I want to instantiate an object from a class I wrote on a different file. What I got is `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) (ArgumentError)`

Here is the main code

```
# ./lib/parking_lot
require_relative './lot.rb'

class ParkingLotInterface

  def initialize(input: $stdin, output: $stdout)
    @input, @output = input, output
    @lot = nil
  end

  def prompt_input
    @lot = Lot.new(10)   
  end
end

parking_lot_interface = ParkingLotInterface.new(input: $stdin, output: $stdout)

parking_lot_interface.prompt_input
```

And here is the object class

```
# ./lib/lot
class Lot
  attr_reader :slots, 

  def initialize(size)
    @slots = Arrays.new(size)
  end
end
```

The error was thrown at the line where I tried to instantiate a new Lot object. Looking at the internet, people who had the same problem got told that they didn't specify `def initialize` in the class, or they mistyped it. However, I did what they all said and I still faced `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) (ArgumentError)`

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the comma after

```
attr_reader :slots,
```

it would be

```
attr_reader :slots
```

And take a look, you are trying to instance Arrays (and must not to be in plural) on lot.rb

```
  def initialize(size)
    @slots = Arrays.new(size)
  end
```

it would be

```
  def initialize(size)
    @slots = Array.new(size)
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, method definitions are expressions as well (in fact, in Ruby, everything is an expression, there are no statements), so they evaluate to an object. Method definition expressions evaluate to a `Symbol` denoting the name of the method that was defined.

So,

```
def initialize(*) end
#=> :initialize
```

In your code, you have a comma after `attr_reader :slots`, which means that you pass two arguments to `attr_reader`, namely the symbol `:slots` and the expression `def initialize(…) … end`. Since Ruby is a strict language, the arguments to `attr_reader` will be evaluated first, before `attr_reader` itself is executed.

So, what happens first is that the method definition expression gets evaluated. This defines a (private) method named `initialize`. It also evaluates to the symbol `:initialize`.

Next, the expression `attr_reader :slots, :initialize` gets evaluated, which defines two methods named `slots` and `initialize`, thus overwriting the method you just defined. Note that this will print a warning:

```
lot.rb:3: warning: method redefined; discarding old initialize
lot.rb:5: warning: previous definition of initialize was here
```

You should always read the warnings, the Ruby developers don't spend the hard work putting them in just for the fun of it!

The solution is to remove the comma telling Ruby to look for a second argument.

There is a second error in your code, namely that you misspelt `Array` within `Lot#initialize`.

And, there are a couple of stylistic improvements that you could make:

- There is no need to pass a path and a filename extension to `require_relative`. It should be `require_relative 'lot'`.
- Un-initialized instance variables evaluate to `nil`, so there is no need to initialize `@lot` to `nil`.
- `$stdin` and `$stdout` are the default argument values of the `stdin:` and `stdout:` keyword parameters, so there is no need to pass them explicitly.
- It is seldom necessary to create an array of a specific size, since Ruby arrays are dynamic and can change their size at any time.

With all this taken in to account, your code would look something like this:

```
# ./lib/parking_lot
require_relative 'lot'

class ParkingLotInterface
  def initialize(input: $stdin, output: $stdout)
    @input, @output = input, output
  end

  def prompt_input
    @lot = Lot.new(10)   
  end
end

parking_lot_interface = ParkingLotInterface.new

parking_lot_interface.prompt_input

# ./lib/lot
class Lot
  attr_reader :slots

  def initialize(size)
    @slots = Array.new(size)
    # could be @slots = []
    # depending on how you use `@slots` later
  end
end
```